# Not sure if I am using before_filter/before_action correctly in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I haven't used Rails in some time now, but I am aware Rails comes with things like

**application_controller.rb**

```
before_filter :login_with_access_token

helper_method :current_user
```

From my understanding, `before_filter` will run the aftersaid method before EVERY action in thus controller. And considering this is the **ApplicationController** it will run it before every action, since everything inherits from the **ApplicationController**.  And I guess a `helper_method` is a method that we check often and can be accessed in our views.

I guess the reason I am kinda confused is I don't fully see why we would need `helper_methods` other than the fact you would want you use them in the views. For example, if I just wanna check if a `person` model is an adult... what would persuade one from choosing a `helper_method` vs. `action method`? Ex.

```
def is_adult?
  person.age > 18
end
```

**Now this is where I am getting confused in my specific problem**. 
There are certain pages that you can only view if you have a `Food` object selected. Meaning, my route:

`get '/user/:user_id/food/:food_id', to: 'units#display_user_food', as: 'display_user_food'`

I proceeded to add a `before_filter :user_has_food`

```
  def user_has_food
    unless UserFood.where(id: params["user_id"]).empty?
      true
    else
      unit_id = params["unit_id"]
      false
      puts "------------ User does not have food :("
      redirect_to "/user/new-food/#{unit_id}"
    end
  end
```

But... now the problem is... I have a very thick controller... there are many actions... and if it hits another action, it just fails, and will attempt to redirect me since `user_has_food` turns out false. Looking at this... it doesn't seem right. *What is the ideal and optimal solution to properly address this problem?*

I would like to do something with the **/app/helpers** folder, but I can't seem to find updated tutorials on how to go about using them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call `before_filter` only for some specific controller `action` like following

```
before_filter :user_has_food, only: [:display_user_food]
```

In `rails 5.0` `before_filter` is deprecated and you should use `before_action`. And if you have only one action to filtered, you can avoid using array, see the bellow snippet

```
before_filter :user_has_food, only: :display_user_food
```

When you use `only` option in `before_filter` it will ignored calling while request comes for other action.

Comment: Okay, that fixed it. Ultimately, if you were to do this, would you approach the problem the same way I did, or would you use something like `helper_method`'s instead?

Comment: I would not use helper method, because helper method is something you use very frequently both views and  controller. I would use before filer. You can make this answer correct if really helps you :)

Answer (score 1):

Helper method is accessible in any view and controller but action methods are bound to object of that particular class. So something like `current_user` that doesn't need any object should be a helper method. 
Rokibul correctly pointed out about using `only: []` syntax to avoid other controller action.
But note that all before_filters syntax are deprecated in Rails 5.0 and will be removed in Rails 5.1, Use `before_action` instead.